# UIWebview with contenteditable - superscript and subscript NOT work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, contenteditable

I have webview with contenteditable and use javascript to do rich text editing. It works with some commands like "Bold" and "Italic" below:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('Bold')"];

[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('Italic')"];
```

But somehow "superscript" and"subscript" below, it doesn't work:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('superscript')"];

[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('subscript')"];
```

Anyone knows, under iOS, do we have similar [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands), so that I can know what commands will work under Safari-UIWebview?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer this regarding UIWebView, but FWIW `document.execCommand('superscript')` works for me in Safari on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with Mac. So this is good info, somehow under iOS6 & iOS7, not every command(like "superscript", "subscript", "indent", "outdent" etc) work.

Comment: Your question is the answer to mine; I did not know there was such a thing as `execCommand`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this page on my iOS7.1 iPad:

http://quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/

Both superscript and subscript work. Looking at the source, the following command is performed: `document.execCommand("superscript", false, null);`

Comment: Thanks for confirming. My bad - my code to skip these Superscript, subscript commands - take out that logic and tried again, these two commands did go through.